# Weird problem with simple HREF link

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm putting a simple href link inside my html page:
http://search.mastertour.co.il/?mode=page&page=12077&lang=rus
the link can be found at the bottom of the page near the cleopatra head image.
Now, while the page is in a subdomain, the link referes to a TLD but the page cannot redirect to the link. It shows a "half-baked" page while trying to access the link directly (not through the html link) shows the page fine.

Any idea???

Comment: Turn on error reporting.  All will be revealed. If you are using PHP, put this at the top of the "half baked page" `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: You mean the page opens in a new window/tab instead of in the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `window.open()`, this is all you need:

```
<a href="http://www.mastertour.co.il/rus/tours/egypt/" target="_new">здесь</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has something to do with the `onclick` attribute you have attached. Do you really need it? Also, i'm guessing you're using it to force that link to open in a new tab/window - you really shouldn't, as the user should have that kind of control.

Comment: You are 100% correct about forcing tabs, but I'm not sure if this is why the page is failing.

Comment: When you try to open the URL manually, the page loads correctly - so my guess is it has something to do with the `onclick` attribute, though I really don't know what :(

Comment: The link works fine in IE7 but not FF3.6.12. I am inclined to agree with jgradim, so go with egrunin's response.